# Create new item and place it into the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

*I am trying to create new object and to store it into the Database but I cannot understand why I am getting the following error: Here you can see the mistake:*

```
Started POST "/cruises" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-26 16:34:59 +0100
Processing by CruisesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OkFmCPhl0pjFezWCsxp+c16wr3j9nbsdLIdgj+PsCMgSDmTzBoEJQ69tB8IA3uNayLRO+LMTi/73YqYCMImtCA==", "cruise"=>{"name"=>"NewAsasa", "ship_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Cruise"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering cruises/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered cruises/_form.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered cruises/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap):
    18: 
    19:   <div class="field">
    20:     <em><%= f.label :ship_id %></em>
    21:      <%= f.collection_radio_buttons( :ship_id, @ships, :id, :name ) %>
    22:   </div>
    23: 
    24:   <div class="actions">
```

*CruiseController - ""here you can see more about the controller below:I just need to write more text because it gives me error when I try to put this code, so do not read this explaination here it is for""*

```
class CruisesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cruise, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :redirect_if_not_found

  # GET /cruises
  # GET /cruises.json
  def index
    @cruises = Cruise.all
  end

  # GET /cruises/1
  # GET /cruises/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /cruises/new
  def new
    @cruise = Cruise.new
    @ships = Ship.all
  end

  # GET /cruises/1/edit
  def edit
     @ships = Ship.all
  end

  # POST /cruises
  # POST /cruises.json
  def create
    @cruise = Cruise.new(cruise_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cruise.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cruise, notice: 'Cruise was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cruise }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cruise.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cruises/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cruises/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cruise.update(cruise_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cruise, notice: 'Cruise was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cruise }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cruise.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cruises/1
  # DELETE /cruises/1.json
  def destroy
    @cruise.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cruises_url, notice: 'Cruise was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cruise
      @cruise = Cruise.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cruise_params
      params.require(:cruise).permit(:name, :ship_id)
    end


end
```

Comment: What's in your `cruises_controller`?

Comment: I added the controller

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are iterating over in your controller is nil.  Based on the code you have shown I am assuming it is @ships.  I bet if you put `puts @ships` in your controller it will log nil.

Answer (score 0):

Your save fails in the `create` action, (rollback transaction) so the `if` condition of the `create` action trigger the `render :new`.

However, it is a render, not a redirect, that mean the `new` action is not executed, and both @cruise and @ship does not exist (undefined).

Finally during the rendering of the `new` view, an error is triggered because @ships is undefined.

EDIT : I made an error, @ships is not nil it just does not exist (undefined).

Comment: Thank you for clarification but how to fix it?

Comment: There is a clue in my explanation.

Comment: I did not get it very well ,so you mean to redirect it but not render?

Comment: That's it. The view wants a @ships, you can initialize it in the create(not recommanded, but it's possible) or redirect, that will respond to the browser to hit the new route instead of rendering new.